# using tap gesture to select row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to click on each cell to activate a `push segue` but because the `view controller` is always in editing mode I cannot click on the cells. In `editing mode`, I have enlarged the `reorder controller` to cover the entire `cell` and then made it invisible so you can drag to reorder `tableview` from anywhere in the cell thus when I click on the cells in editing mode, I'm actually clicking on the reorder controller. Please do not tell me to set the tableview property of `allowsSelectionDuringEditing` to YES as I have already done that and it still does not let me select the cell because it is being covered by the reorder controller which was added to the cell as a subview.

My solution was to prepare a new `push segue` via a `tap` gesture in the `cell` which would still activate even if the cell was covered by its `reorder controller`. However, the data that is sent over to the `view` that is called by the `segue` is always from the first `cell` no matter which cell I click in. Why does this happen? Any help is appreciated.

this is how I changed my reorder control

```
-(void) resizeReorderControl: (UITableView *)tableView reorderCell:(UITableViewCell *)bCell{
    //  Grip customization code goes in here...
    UIView* reorderControl = [bCell huntedSubviewWithClassName:@"UITableViewCellReorderControl"];

    UIView* resizedGripView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetMaxX(reorderControl.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(reorderControl.frame))];
    [resizedGripView addSubview:reorderControl];
    [bCell addSubview:resizedGripView];

    CGSize sizeDifference = CGSizeMake(resizedGripView.frame.size.width - reorderControl.frame.size.width, resizedGripView.frame.size.height - reorderControl.frame.size.height);
    CGSize transformRatio = CGSizeMake(resizedGripView.frame.size.width / reorderControl.frame.size.width, resizedGripView.frame.size.height / reorderControl.frame.size.height);

    //  Original transform
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    //  Scale custom view so grip will fill entire cell
    transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, transformRatio.width, transformRatio.height);

    //  Move custom view so the grip's top left aligns with the cell's top left
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -sizeDifference.width / 2.0, -sizeDifference.height / 2.0);

    [resizedGripView setTransform:transform];

    for(UIImageView* cellGrip in reorderControl.subviews)
    {
        if([cellGrip isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
            [cellGrip setImage:nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's solution that works for me.

To find reorder control in iOS7, I've changed the code and added one more check

```
-(void) resizeReorderControl: (UITableView *)tableView reorderCell:(UITableViewCell *)bCell{
    ...
    UIView* reorderControl = [bCell huntedSubviewWithClassName:@"UITableViewCellReorderControl"];
        if (!reorderControl) {
            reorderControl = [bCell huntedSubviewWithClassName:@"UITableViewCellScrollView"]; // for iOS7
        }
    ...
    //Then I added my gesture recognizer:
    ...
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [reorderControl addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    ...
}
```

Add to your view controller declaration `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` delegate, your view controller interface should look like this:

```
@interface ViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

Then implement delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

Also you need to implement method that we specified in `UITapGestureRecognizer` init method:

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:[sender locationInView:self.tableView]];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    // If you have custom logic in table view delegate method, also invoke this method too
    [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: I have already tried to set the allowsSelectionDuringEditing property of tableView to YES but that does not work because in editing, the cell is covered by the reorder controller (which i made invisible but it's still there) so I cannot select it. the cell has a subview which covers the cell which is what prevents it from being selected.

Comment: I do not understand ur last two sentences. Which property are you referring to? I only have one instance of tableview so im not sure what you mean?

Comment: What do you mean by term `reorder controller`?

Comment: [reorder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/showsReorderControl)

Comment: go to showsReorderControl in property. this is the thing you click and drag to move your cell around via moveRowAtIndexPath: toIndexPath

Comment: @snapfish So you want to move cells with this control or not? Or you want both moving and selecting?

Comment: @snapfish Also, afaik it only cover right part of cell (right accessory view). Other parts will still respond to touch well

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48438/discussion-between-ossir-and-snapfish)